# form_checkbox() returns string instead of array in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

Here's a bit of code from a codeigniter View:

```
   <li>
      <label>Assign volunteer to event:</label><br />
      <? foreach ($all_vols as $vol) :?>
        <?=form_checkbox('volunteers', $vol) ?>
        <?=$vol['username']?>
        <br />
      <? endforeach ?>  
    </li>
```

I'm expecting there to be an array named `volunteers` in the `$_POST` variable. Instead, what I'm getting is `'volunteers' => string('array')`. Any thoughts what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an array as a second argument of form_checkbox() when used in this way, and `$vol` is likely to be an array as you use `$vol['username']` later on. You're confounding the form helper, which takes the first parameter to be used as the 'name' attribute and the second as its 'value'.

Try:

```
<? foreach ($all_vols as $vol) :?>
        <?=form_checkbox('volunteers[]', $vol['username']) ?>
        <?=$vol['username']?>
        <br />
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Indeed! My problem was that I was passing an array as the second parameter to the form helper. Consequently, the form-helper gave each checkbox the value of "array". I fixed that problem as per your suggestions (and confirmed in the source that the values are correct). Now, however, I just get the last checkbox value in $_POST['volunteers']. Shouldn't there be an array of all the selected values? Why do I only get the last value?

Comment: @sarsinmypockets yeah sorry I forgot, you need to add brackets to volunteer, so that it becomes an array of values (print_r to see the result). Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

From CI's [userguide](http://file:///home/atno/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'newsletter',
    'id'          => 'newsletter',
    'value'       => 'accept',
    'checked'     => TRUE,
    'style'       => 'margin:10px',
    );

echo form_checkbox($data);

// Would produce:

<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="accept" checked="checked" style="margin:10px" />
```

Your array should contain the data need it to populate the checkbox. So you might wanna change your checkbox to `<?=form_checkbox($vol) ?>` if you're sure it contains what is needed to populate the field.

Answer (score 1):

The docs at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html suggest using a string as the first argument (in your case "volunteers") will produce an `<input type="checkbox" />` of that name while using `$vol` for the attribute-value pairs inside the input tag. Is this what you want? If so, you will apparently end up with a "username" attribute.