# CodeIgniter: Create checkboxes in form on view so that multiple selections are submitted as an array

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller, checkbox

I am following [nettut+ tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/) for pagination and to store POST inputs as querystrings in db. So far, everything works fine until, suppose if I get an array as POST input, I am unable to loop through it and get all the array values and to store into query_array (i.e., store array within array).

The snippets below:

```
$query_array = array(
'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
'minage' => $this->input->post('minage'),
'maxage' => $this->input->post('maxage'),
'Citizenship' => $this->input->post('citizenship'), // checkboxes with name citizenship[]
);
```

This returns only last stored array value in Citizenship.

The output array:

```
Array ( [gender] => 1 [minage] => 18 [maxage] => 24 [Citizenship] => 2 )
```

makes the query string as:

```
&gender=1&minage=18&maxage=24&Citizenship=2
```

But, my requirement is to get all the values of 'Citizenship' array instead of last stored value.

The output required to make query string:

```
Array ( [gender] => 1 [minage] => 18 [maxage] => 24 [Citizenship] => 2 [Citizenship] => 4 [Citizenship] => 6 )
```

The query string :

```
&gender=1&minage=18&maxage=24&Citizenship[]=2&Citizenship[]=4&Citizenship[]=6
```

Comment: And [Make array from checkbox form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4516847/2943403) and [form_checkbox() returns string instead of array in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6349156/2943403) and [getting a checkbox array value from POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10655355/2943403) and [why I am getting string instead of array from my checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9663256/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like code ignighter supports un-named multidimensional arrays as input without a bit of hacking.

If you can access raw $_POST data try replacing

```
$this->input->post('citizenship')
```

with

```
array_map('intval',$_POST['citizenship'])
```

Alternativly add keys to your post data:

```
&gender=1&minage=18&maxage=24&Citizenship[0]=2&Citizenship[1]=4&Citizenship[2]=6
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I just looped through the POST array and got the individual array key & pair values.

```
foreach($_POST['Citizenship'] as $k => $v) {
    $Citizenship[$v] = $v;
}
```

Hope this helps someone who face similar problem.