# getting a checkbox array value from POST

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

i am posting an array of checkboxes. and i cant get it to work. i didnt include the proper syntax in the foreach loop to keep it simple. but it is working. i tested in by trying to do the same thing with a text field instead of a checkbox and it worked with the textfield.

```
<form method="post">
<?php 
foreach{
echo'
<input id="'.$userid.'" value="'.$userid.'"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
<input type="submit">';
}
?>
</form>
```

here is the part that is not working. it is echoing 'invite' instead of array.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
$invite = $_POST['invite'];
echo $invite;
}
```

Comment: `$invite` is an array.  Try `print_r($invite);` instead of `echo`

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` and see what is actually set.

Comment: it says 'invite' when i do print_r

Comment: Try adding multiple checkbox named 'invite[]'. You'll get the output as an array. And you shouldn't be using <Form ** inside the loop as there'll always be single instance of invite in each form.

Comment: I think your PHP code is still wrong.  Your `foreach` shouldn't be inside your `echo` and your HTML is inside of you `<?PHP ?>` tags.

Comment: it isnt exactly like that in my code. i know this isnt the issue. but i tried doing the exact same thing with a text field, and it worked. the issue is specific to the checkbox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your $_POST array contains the invite array, so reading it out as

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
  $invite = $_POST['invite'];
  echo $invite;
}
?>
```

won't work since it's an array. You have to loop through the array to get all of the values.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['invite'])) {
    foreach($_POST['invite'] as $value){
      echo $value;
    }
  } else {
    $value = $_POST['invite'];
    echo $value;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: when i tried this. i got Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_learning\site_pages\groups_page.php on line 95

Comment: Can you copy/paste the full results of an `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: I edited my answer to add a check of whether the invite value is an array or string. If you only pass one checked invite checkbox it will be a string value. That may fix the error you are receiving.

Comment: here is the <pre><pre> results Array
(
    [invite] => Invite
    [rememberme] => undefine
)

Comment: i tried the edited for loop. and i still got an undefined variable. Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_learning\site_pages\groups_page.php on line 99
i think the issue has to be with the data before it is being POSTED. but when i inspect the element. the data in the html is all correct. so the problem is somewhere from before the html is sent.

Comment: i think that the name of the $_POST['invite'] was conflicting with something else. so i changed it to $_POST['inviter'] and it started working

Comment: This did not work for me. But the answer that @Ecropolis gave below did

Answer (score 15):

I just used the following code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="user1" value="user1"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
    <input id="user2" value="user2"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
        $invite = $_POST['invite'];
        print_r($invite);
    }
?>
```

When I checked both boxes, the output was:

```
Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 )
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it gives you a working example to reference and hopefully helps you solve the problem.

Comment: thanks. my code must have some bug, type or something i am not seeing. the weird part is that i tried this exact same thing with a text field, and it worked. so the issue is related specifically to the checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the implode() function as an alternative. This will convert the array into a list. The first param is how you want the items separated. Here I have used a comma with a space after it.

```
$invite = implode(', ', $_POST['invite']);
echo $invite;
```

Comment: many thanks, sir! this just helped me save about 1 hour of research. i am LOVING the implode right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if you do the input like this
<input id="'.$userid.'" value="'.$userid.'"  name="invite['.$userid.']" type="checkbox">

// you can access the value directly like this:
$invite = $_POST['invite'][$userid];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `<form>` element is inside the foreach loop, you are generating multiple forms.  I assume you want multiple checkboxes in one form.

Try this...

```
<form method="post">
foreach{
<?php echo'
<input id="'.$userid.'" value="'.$userid.'"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
<input type="submit">';
?>
}
</form>
```

Comment: Nice catch.  I would even move the submit button outside the loop as well.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake i made when i typed it in the question. the code isnt really like that.