# How to get checkbox values in array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have an image upload form that looks like this:
[image: Gallery Screenshot]

The code to generate tag checkboxes:

```
foreach($tag as $tagid => $tagname) {
  echo "<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"img_tags[]\" value=\"".$tagid."\">".$tagname."</label>";
}
```

Then in PHP I want to read values of this checkboxes for each image. I want img_tags to be 2D array so I can loop over it and check values for each picture. Is this possible?

Output of:

```
$img_tags = $_POST['img_tags'];↵
foreach($img_tags as $t) {↵
    print_r($t);↵
}↵
```

is: 12121, which I don't understand at all.

Comment: You can use names like for image `img_tags[pic1][name]` and for tags `img_tags[pic1][tags]`

Comment: If you Google your exact title, you'll see your question is a duplicate of [getting a checkbox array value from POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655355/getting-a-checkbox-array-value-from-post)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 2d array in a `$_POST` variable then you need to express that in the names.

```
name="img_tags[level_1_key][]"
```

Comment: Ok, I tried `name=\"img_tags[".$counter."][]\"` , where $counter is from while loop going through all images, and in PHP to get it : `$img_tags = $_POST['img_tags['.$key.']'];`. Generated HTML looks fine: `name="img_tags[1][]"` but I get `Undefined index: img_tags[1]`.

Comment: That's because it is an array (which is what you asked for). `$_POST['img_tags'][1]`