# How to store the names of checkboxes of a form to a php arrray

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

First off, I want to store the names of these checkboxes which are submitted, and not their values.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","notifier");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");

echo "Enter the attendance. Please untick for 'ABSENT' students and submit";
echo "<br>";
echo "<form action=\"d.php\" method=\"post\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<br>" .$row['classrollno'] . "&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" . $row['studentid'] . "\" value=\"P\" checked>";
}
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

This code simply fetches a column of student rollnumberss from student table, prints them, and as well as prints a checkbox infront of them which is checked by default.
Names of checkboxes will be the student id (varchar, another column).

Now since All Checked checkboxes, that is the checboxes which will be submitted to next page will have same default value "P", I m not concerned about their values.

How do I store the names of these checkboxes in an array, and later on use it to perform updation in table for all these student id's?

Comment: Then try putting the data you actually need as a value, and check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655355/getting-a-checkbox-array-value-from-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<br>' .$row['classrollno'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="studentId[]" value="' . $row['studentid'] . '" checked />';
}
```

Then, when you process the form, the `$_POST['studentId']` variable will contain an array with all the id's.

Since the value that will probably be inserted in the db is 'P' for every student, you wouldn't need to include it in your form, but just hardcode it in your query.

Comment: Excellent solution marty. I was trying to save the names instead of values, and you showed me way how I can switch the name and value in my form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keep adding the names to an array. Its straight forward.

Declare `$allStudentIds = array();` outside `while` loop. Then, to store in that array,

```
$allStudentIds[] = $row['studentid'];
```

Since you wanted to use these values later, you can directly store them inside a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['allStudentIds'][] = $row['studentid'];
```

In above case, `$_SESSION['allStudentIds']` will be an array of all student ids selected.

**Note:** You need to start session using `session_start()` as the first line in the script after opening `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, in the fetching while loop, define an array and set each checkbox value to one of its elements then assign it as a session variable:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<br>" .$row['classrollno'] . "&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" . $row['studentid'] . "\" value=\"P\" checked>";
$names[] = $row['studentid'];
}
```

Then,

```
$_SESSION['names'] = $names;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you are mixing the View (the name of the checkbox in HTML) and the Model/Data (which the student_id you are getting from your DB query ie. the $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) in the while loop).

All you need to do is create an empty array (eg. $studentid_arr) before the loop and after the echo statement which is just contributing to the view (the HTML) you do some work with your data. What you want to do currently is to store the student_ids (and not the name of the checkbox) in your $studentid_arr.

That can be done with a simple `array_push ($studentid_arr,$row['studentid']);`

So your while loop would look like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<br>" .$row['classrollno'] . "&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" . $row['studentid'] . "\" value=\"P\" checked>";
    array_push ($studentid_arr,$row['studentid']);
}
```

Now you can just POST this PHP array to your next script which is expecting these values. (which is what I assume you mean by submitting to the next page)

Comment: Marty's solution is more elegant. It makes use of form input arrays as described at http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays