# How to validate address field in Codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to apply some validation rules to my form data in CodeIgniter.

Expected Allowed output example like this: **22-some society, some street, city. 223399**

What I Entered for check the validation: **42-some Society-3, some street. arcade @##***

This is my function which I use to validate the address.

```
function addr_line1($addr_line1) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i',$addr_line1) !== FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    $this->form_validation->set_message('addr_line1', 'allow only space,comma,dot,numbers and alphabets.');

    return FALSE;
}
```

Now I put all my validation in the **config/form_validation.php**

```
array(
        'field' => 'addr_line1',
        'label' => 'Address Line One',
        'rules' => 'required|max_length[100]|callback_addr_line1'            
    ),
```

After all this,I didn't get any validation error. 
Am I not following the proper process?
or what should the regex code to validate this type of data?

Comment: @dhruv jadia can you help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change from

```
function addr_line1($addr_line1) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i',$addr_line1) !== FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    $this->form_validation->set_message('addr_line1', 'allow only space,comma,dot,numbers and alphabets.');

    return FALSE;
}
```

to

```
function addr_line1($addr_line1) {
    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $addr_line1))
    {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('addr_line1', 'allow only space,comma,dot,numbers and alphabets.');
    }else{
          return true;
    }
}
```

**Note:-** you can replace `£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-` with your disallowed character

Comment: @ankit suthar : answer provided

Comment: Thanks Your Answer Help Me to get the proper way of getting a perfect regex. Thx @dhruvjadia

Answer (score 0):

After Your suggestion and help, I finally found the correct Function.

```
 function _validAddressCheck($addr_line1) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z .,-]+$/',$addr_line1)){
         return TRUE;
    } else {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('_validAddressCheck', 'Only Allowed space, comma, dot, dash, numbers and alphabets.');

    return FALSE;
    }

}
```

I found that some rules which we have to follow if we are applying callback to the validation.

1. I have created config validation array at the application/config/form_validation.php
2. Put the callback function at the controller where I called that validations.

Find this link for creating a regex and test that. [Link](http://www.regextester.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <tr>
         <td>
            <label for="address">Address:</label></td><td>
            <textarea  name="address" placeholder="Write 
            something.."><?php echo set_value('address'); ?> </textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="err_msg">
                <?php
                echo form_error('address');
                ?>
            </p>    
        </td>
```

in route page:-

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('address','add','required|exact_length[18]',array('required'=>"Please Enter Address",'exact_length'=>"Please Enter At Least 10 Character"));
```

Comment: 1) Insert the html code into the file of the view/ index.php