# how to insert multiple check box in web service codeigniter?

Tags: android, json, codeigniter

I've created a web service in codeigniter.
so here my controller:

```
public function insertsebab(){

    $id=$this->input->post('id_konsultasi');
    $sebab=$this->input->post('kd_sebab');

    $data = array(
        'id_konsultasi'     =>$id,
        'kd_sebab'      => $sebab, 
    );

    $konsultasi = $this->class_model->insertsebab($data);
    if(count($konsultasi) > 0 ){
        $json["STATUS"] = "SUCCESS";
        $json["MESSAGE"] = "Data Berhasil Di Simpan";
        $json["DATA"] = (object) array();

    }
    else{
        $json["STATUS"] = "GAGAL";
        $json["MESSAGE"] = "No data found in database";
        $json["DATA"] = (object) array();
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

The code above explains how to insert data more than one in checkbox,but actually data save only one.
[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssU8E.png)

so,how to create insert multiple check box in web service codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to do a foreach with the post name.
here a same question :
[Get multiple values of checkbox in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104065/get-multiple-values-of-checkbox-in-codeigniter)

I wish it helps you.